# Is it possible to use OR in search queries?

Tags: discussion, support, search

My current search query is this:

```
[worklight] is:question answers:0 duplicate:no closed:no
```

However, [worklight](/questions/tagged/worklight) has several other related tags, such as: [worklight-security](/questions/tagged/worklight-security), [worklight-console](/questions/tagged/worklight-console), [worklight-rpe](/questions/tagged/worklight-rpe) and so on.

I would like to modify my search query so that it would return any result contain any of the tags. Something like this:

```
[worklight] or [worklight-console] or ...[ ] ... is:question answers:0 duplicate:no closed:no
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use wildcards with your tag

```
[*worklight*] is:question answers:0 duplicate:no closed:no
```

#### [Result](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B*worklight*%5D%20is:question%20answers:0%20duplicate:no%20closed:no)

Comment: zzz fastest gun something...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `or` works in search queries. For example, [`[worklight] or  [worklight-adapters] or  [worklight-studio]  is:question answers:0 duplicate:no closed:no`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bworklight%5D%20or%20%20%5Bworklight-adapters%5D%20or%20%20%5Bworklight-studio%5D%20%20is:question%20answers:0%20duplicate:no%20closed:no)

So does [`[worklight*] is:question answers:0 duplicate:no closed:no`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bworklight*%5D%20is:question%20answers:0%20duplicate:no%20closed:no) (I doubt wildcards work outside of tags though)